# How to use ScriptEngine in C#

Tags: c#, scripting, code-analysis, roslyn

I have installed Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting via NU-get. When I try

```
var engine = new ScriptEngine();
```

it shows me the error: The type or namespace 'ScripEngine' could not be found.

I just can't figure out what's wrong, how do I use it?

Comment: For anyone confused about this, I believe IronPython has a class called ScriptEngine used for running Python scripts in C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No such class exists.

Instead, use [`CSharpScript.Create()`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting/CSharpScript.cs,24)